# Mixin with a Generic Constraint not working

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-mixins

I was trying to create a mixin as follows -

```
class TestModel {
    name?: string;
}

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function mixinA<T extends TestModel>(base: Constructor<T>): Constructor<T & {id?: string}>  {
    class Dummy extends base {
        id?: string;
    }
    return Dummy as Constructor<T & {id?: string}>;
}
```

This throws the following error -

```
Class 'Dummy' incorrectly extends base class 'T'.
  'Dummy' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TestModel'.
```

Why the fact that T could be instantiated with a different subtype effect the Dummy extending a Class T, and even if it did, why does the code below work without any error -

```
function mixinA<T extends Constructor<TestModel>>(base: T): T & Constructor<{id?: string}>  {
    class Dummy extends base {
        id?: string;
    }
    return Dummy as T & Constructor<{id?: string}>;
}
```

It is the same code except the Generic Type extends the Constructor itself instead of the Object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question makes sense to me, as I've just run into the same issue. The question is, why does TypeScript give the error that it does for the first example, and what does it mean? The "problem" can be "fixed" by using the code in the second example, but it isn't clear to @Akshat - or to me - why the second example works and the first one doesn't.

Comment: Also - @Akshat - you don't need to specify a return type on your `mixinA()` function - TypeScript will infer that for you automatically from the code. You can then just return your `Dummy` class directly, instead of having to cast and re-specify its structure before returning it.

Comment: @DanKing In order to implement mixins, you can consider [this approach](https://catchts.com/oop-style)

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, but I prefer Akshat's approach: it's a lot cleaner, since it relies purely on the language's natural inheritance hierarchy to do everything you need, and it doesn't require any object or prototype mutation. It also gives you complete type inference / type safety when used with TypeScript.

Comment: @DanKing sure, just wanted you to be aware about alternative approach

Comment: @DanKing, right, I'll just remove the return types from example. I am considering raise a bug in the TypeScript repo as I could not find any good reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it genuinely is a bug, or just something in the type system that I've failed to get my head round!